Show Multiple Data in a single cell using datatables
Is there any way to get data from multiple columns and display them inside a cell using datatables column function as shown in the example below.



SN
Name
Category




1
First
Cat A: Done




Cat B: Done




Cat C: Done


2
Second
Cat A: Done




Cat B: Not Done




Cat C: Pending



There are three categories and every row has data in the category. Basically what is intended is that every  element except the category column to have a rowspan of 3. Is there any way it can be done?
